# How to maintain loading order of script in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have added following module via Require.JS. Everything works fine But I want to know how to load them without using multiple require statement in the same order mentioned below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['common'],function()
{  require(['jquery','fastclick','nprogress','charts','underscore','spinner'],function()
  {
    require(['firstDashboardController']);
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your `firstDashboardController` as a proper AMD module, with dependencies:

```
define(['jquery','fastclick','nprogress','charts','underscore','spinner'], ...
```

This will guarantee that everything listed in your dependencies will load first.

People typically put RequireJS configuration in their `common` module. I recommend against loading configuration as a module. It is preferable to just load with with a `script` element, just after you load RequireJS itself. This way you are sure that the configuration is always loaded when you need it. Otherwise, you have to play rigmaroles with nested `require` calls like you show in your question.

If you do all of the above, then you can just do:

```
require(['firstDashboardController']);
```

when you need it, without having to nest `require` calls.